# Getting Error installing rpy2 on Windows7

Tags: error-handling, rpy2

**Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.**

I did exactly this:

### 3. Define environmental variables

Control Panel | Advanced tab | Environmental Variables

define the following: RHOME, R_HOME, R_USER

examples

```
`RHOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1
+R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1
+R_USER: C:\Users\username\Documents`
```

### 4. Append path to R (and Rtools) executable(s) to PATH

Control Panel | Advanced tab | Environmental Variables

example paths: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\i386; C:\Rtools\bin

However, I do not undestand point three exactly. Could you explain the meaning behind RHOME, R_HOME, R_USER? Thank you, it is really urgent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it a lot easier to grab the [binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) installer from the repository at the University of California at Irvine.

Test with this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
print robjects.r('pi')
```

Other things to look at:

- In Windows, when you set an environment variable via the control panel, you'll have to restart the command shell for it to be accepted.
- R_HOME points to the R distribution.  R_USER is where you would store local files.  Ideally, if you set these as user variables, your path can then reference %R_HOME% instead o the hard-coded path.  There is more information on Windows' handling of the two kinds of environment variables [here](https://superuser.com/questions/27826/why-cant-windows-handle-an-environment-variable-in-path).

Comment: Wow man! Thank you for your comment! I think it works now but I still receive this error message:                              import rpy2.robjects as robjects
print robjects.r('pi')

Unable to unlink tempfile c:\users\X\appdata\local\temp\tmpiqhlbp
[1] 3.141593